# Tensorflow outputs accuracy 1 but all the results are the same (and wrong)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a Tensorflow Neural Network, but can't get it to work correctly. It always outputs the same values for every observation. Tried to change activations functions, changing the learning rate, reshaping tensors and arrays, I'm missing something here.

The dataset is entirely numerical.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
X = np.array(df[["area","bathrooms", "sq_price"]])
y = df[["price"]]
y = np.array(y).reshape([47, 1])

normalizer = Normalizer()
X = normalizer.fit_transform(X)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
X_test = np.array(X_test, dtype='float32')
y_test = np.array(y_test, dtype="float32")
X_test.shape

n_inputs = len(X_train[0])
n_hidden = 5
n_outputs = 1
lr = 0.001
epochs = 5000
batch_size = 1

xph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_inputs])
yph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_outputs])

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_inputs, n_hidden], stddev=0.1))
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden, n_outputs], stddev=0.1))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([n_hidden]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([n_outputs]))

def feed_forward(X, W1, W2, b1, b2):
    l1 = tf.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W1), b1))
    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, W2),b2)
    return l2

output = feed_forward(xph, W1, W2, b1, b2)

error = tf.reduce_mean((output - yph)**2)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr).minimize(error)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(output,1), tf.argmax(yph,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print("Weights 1 before training:\n ", sess.run([W1]), "\n")
    for i in range(epochs):
        rand_ind = np.random.randint(len(X_train), size = batch_size)
        loss = sess.run([optimizer], feed_dict={xph: X_train[rand_ind], yph: y_train[rand_ind]})
        if i == (epochs-1):
            print("Done!\n")

    print("Weights 1 after training: \n", sess.run([W1]), "\n")
    print("Accuracy: ", sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={xph:X_test, yph:y_test}), "\n")
    print("Results for testing:\n ", sess.run(feed_forward(X_test, W1, W2, b1, b2), feed_dict={xph: X_test}), "\n")
    print("Expected values:\n ", y_test)
```

The output of the code:

```
Weights 1 before training:
[array([[ 0.02620826, -0.11837681,  0.01349821,  0.04195584,  0.14087772],
       [-0.10512593,  0.1383599 , -0.0632275 ,  0.07759375, -0.09907298],
       [-0.14932911,  0.13720822,  0.15072195, -0.09748196,  0.08388615]],
      dtype=float32)]

Done!

Weights 1 after training:
 [array([[ 1.0387952e+01,  1.7232073e+01,  2.9152514e+01, -1.8471668e+01,
         2.2215986e+01],
       [-8.4001064e-02,  1.7373289e-01, -3.8207369e-03,  3.9849356e-02,
        -5.4067656e-02],
       [ 5.5025685e-01,  1.3086454e+00,  2.1180787e+00, -1.3474523e+00,
         1.5743145e+00]], dtype=float32)]

Accuracy:  1.0

Results for testing:
  [[340043.88]
 [340043.88]
 [340043.88]
 [340043.88]
 [340043.88]
 [340043.88]
 [340043.88]
 [340043.88]
 [340043.88]
 [340043.88]]

Expected values:
  [[349900.]
 [369000.]
 [573900.]
 [252900.]
 [299900.]
 [329900.]
 [449900.]
 [285900.]
 [212000.]
 [229900.]]
```

Comment: If you have the price per sq foot and the square footage what do you hope to achieve with your neural network, multiplication?

Comment: I'm just building it to learn, not to actually make use of the results, so I'm just trying to understand why the network is not working properly.